# Elementary set theory relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $U = A \backslash B$ , do we then have $A \backslash U = B$ or just $A \backslash U \subseteq B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the case that $B$ is **not** a subset of $A$.

Comment: ah, so the answer is no, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** To understand what is $A\setminus U$ you need to understand what
elements of $A$ are also in $U$.

Those are exactly the elements that are not also in $B$, what are
we left with ?

I suggest you draw a venn diagram to see things more clearly

Answer (score 1):

We have that $$X\setminus Y = X \cap Y^c.$$

Using this identity your question is:

$$\text{Does }U = A \cap B^c\text{ imply } A\cap U^c = B \text{ ?}$$

Let's see:

\begin{align}
A \cap U^c &= A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c \\
&= A \cap(A^c \cup B) \\
&= (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B) \\
&= \varnothing \cup (A \cap B) = A \cap B
\end{align}

Surely $A \cap B \subseteq B$, but without any assumptions $A \cap B \neq B$. The last part is true if and only if $B \subseteq A$, so to find a counterexample, take $A = \varnothing$ and $B = \{\spadesuit\}$. Now, the premise tells us that $U = A \setminus B = \varnothing$, but $A \setminus U = \varnothing \neq \{\spadesuit\} = B$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$